# How do I limit results to 10 customers for each status in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a customers table with status_id and statuses table. I may have a handful of statuses where I need up to a max of 10 customers per status.

```
select * from customers
join statuses on customers.status_id = statuses.id
where statuses.id in (18, 19, 20)
```

Where do I add the limit? Tried messing with sub queries but I’m not making much progress.

Just trying to understand how to do it in MySQL before moving to eloquent.

Comment: You show the SQL query. can you add your code instead? How you do that in SQL you could have found online, no? How you limit a query in Eloquent you can find in the laravel docs faster than asking a question here

Comment: Please can you add the code that is generating this query.

Comment: Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just trying to understand how to do it in MySQL

```sql
with cte As (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by statuses.id order by ???) rownumber
    from customers
    join statuses on customers.status_id = statuses.id
    where statuses.id in (18, 19, 20)
)
select * 
from cte 
where rownumber <= 10;
```

MySQL 8+ needed.

Comment: This worked great. I think I changed it to be partition by customers.status_id but this did the trick.